# Crontab running at unintended times

Tags: cron

I am trying to run a script Monday through Friday every 2 hours during working hours (9 am - 4 pm).

I tried this:
`0 09-16/2 * * 1-5 /local/bin/script.sh`

But now my script runs Monday through Friday from 2 AM to 8 AM. I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Could it be a time zone problem? What time zone are you in?

Comment: mm maybe! let me try. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
0   9,11,13,15  *   *   1,2,3,4,5   /local/bin/script.sh
```